# How can I add Ubuntu as a profile option in Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

I just installed the new Windows Terminal from Windows stores. I also have installed Ubuntu 18.04 WSL. But I am getting only two types of terminal options in Windows Terminal. How I can get the option of Ubuntu terminal in it. Also, I want cmd to be my default terminal in it rather than PowerShell.

Comment: Just install **Windows Subsystem for Linux**.

Use command: `wsl --install`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to **change settings**

Click "Settings" in right top corner of above image, the file `profile.json` file will be opened. Then inside the word `"profiles"` in `profile.json` file, add below snippet.

```json
        {
            "guid": "{78e390db-1bff-4533-9d7c-20f53d8bafa1}",
            "name": "WSL",
            "colorscheme": "Campbell",
            "historySize": 9001,
            "snapOnInput": true,
            "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "cursorShape": "bar",
            "commandline": "wsl ~",
            "fontFace": "Consolas",
            "fontSize": 12,
            "acrylicOpacity": 0.75,
            "useAcrylic": true,
            "closeOnExit": false,
            "padding": "0, 0, 0, 0"
        }
```

Near the word `"schemes"` in `profile.json` file, you need to update below:

```json
"schemes": [
        {
            "name": "Campbell",
            "foreground": "#A7B191", 
            "background": "#0C0C0C",
            "colors": [
                "#0C0C0C",
                "#C50F1F",
                "#13A10E",
                "#C19C00",
                "#0037DA",
                "#881798",
                "#3A96DD",
                "#CCCCCC",
                "#767676",
                "#E74856",
                "#16C60C",
                "#F9F1A5",
                "#3B78FF",
                "#B4009E",
                "#61D6D6",
                "#F2F2F2"
            ]
        }
```

The complete setting file (profile.json) which can be obtained [here](https://github.com/yanglr/WindowsDevTools/blob/master/awosomeTerminal/profile-my.json).

Actually, the WSL here is Ubuntu.

**Besides, you can add icons to different types of tabs.**

You can add icons for the Ubuntu profile to this folder:

```
$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bb\RoamingState
```

I put some 32x32 PNG in this folder, and then in `profile.json` I can reference the image resource with the path starting with `ms-appdata://` .

The icon is available here:
[Icons](https://github.com/yanglr/WindowsDevTools/tree/master/awosomeTerminal/icons)

Then replace the contents of the new `profile-withIcons.json` file below with the previous settings.
[profile-withIcons.json](https://github.com/yanglr/WindowsDevTools/blob/master/awosomeTerminal/profile-withIcons.json)

After finishing the contents of the folder is like this:

[image: Dir]

The final result is:

[image: Icons]

Comment: why this feature is not out of of the box, whenever I install any new WSL?

Comment: Maybe by design, you can submit issue here https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues .

Comment: Really liked the schema

Answer (score 34):

An even easier option: Go to `Settings` -> `Apps` -> `Apps and features` -> find `Terminal` in the list -> select `Advanced options` then choose `Reset`.

Comment: This worked for me as I had installed Terminal before Ubuntu. This seems to be a newer feature of the terminal ootb integration

Comment: Thank you! People kept writing that Ubuntu was supposed to show up automatically but it wasn't. After resetting it was there!

Comment: Warning: This will reset your settings.json file, so you'll lose any customization you had made. You might want to backup your settings.json file so you can easily compare and reapply your customization after resetting.

Comment: After reading this I've just restarted(close and open again) the Terminal app and and automatically found newly installed Ubuntu and created 2 new profiles(one is broken though :))

Answer (score 10):

For me after installing Ubuntu from Microsoft Store it is appeared like this, it should also work.

```
        {
            "guid": "{2c4de342-38b7-51cf-b940-2309a097f518}",
            "hidden": false,
            "name": "Ubuntu",
            "source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl",
        }
```

Default there will be a penguin icon, you can add your own like this;

```
"icon": "ms-appdata:///roaming/ubuntu_32px.png"
```

You can place your icon file here like mentioned above.

```
$env:LOCALAPPDATA\packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\RoamingState
```

Answer (score 5):

I noticed that installing Windows Terminal when the Ubuntu WSL is already installed automatically adds the Ubuntu profile to the WT. So reinstalling WT might be the quickest solution.

Comment: As of 2021-07-27, this was the quickest and easiest solution for me. I installed WT first, then WSL2 and Ubuntu, but there was no profile. After reinstalling WT, the profile was populated automatically. Note that I'm not using Windows Terminal Preview, just the standard edition.

Comment: Reinstalled, still but still having penguins. And it lost the settings.json.

Answer (score 5):

If Windows Terminal is already installed prior to Ubuntu WSL form the app store, open the Ubuntu app, let it install, enter a new username and password. This will automatically add an Ubuntu profile to Windows Terminal.

Comment: And if not add automatically the new profile ?